# Best way to automatically move files from google drive to local storage?

Tags: android, windows, backup, google-drive-api, file-transfer

My phone fills up the google drive with pictures and videos. I would want automatically move new files from google drive to local storage instead to free space from the drive. What would be the best practice using Windows as local machine? I'm open to some alternatives as well :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to develop application with google drive SDK
 [Check This](https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-android-ui)

and [check this is also](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/TAOJ675mASc)

Comment: That seems like overcomplicating. Some script that moves files automatically from local (windows) gdrive folders when they are added to other location. So gdrive application mirrors the changes => More free space to the server?